# How to insert value into a big int column correctly in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert data into a table. and I am receiving this error code 
,16,10) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)

```
Lookup Error - MySQL Database Error: Incorrect integer value: 'BETA' for column
```

I am inserting data into a bigint column.
I tried to convert the value to big int and that did not work.

This is what I have done

```
CAST(CONV(CASE WHEN LENGTH(MID) = 16 THEN MID ELSE 0 END ,16,10) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS MerchentNum
```

What is the issue with this, I can't get over this error.

Thanks

Comment: Is `MID` a variable? Can you show us its value if possible?

Comment: values are mostly 16 digites numbers but it starts from 0 - 16 digit number

Comment: 'BETA' seems like something in your data, not specific to MySQL.  Can you show where `MID` comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by committing out the following line in my.ini file
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

I added a pound sign # in front of it to comment it out and that worked for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as:

```
CAST('18446744073709551605' AS UNSIGNED)
```

Or `SIGNED` as the case may be.